# Is there an addon to quickly make realistic (diffuse, bump, specular, e.t.c.) materials?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, add-on

Is there an add-on or a built in way to automatically make a material (or node tree) from a collection of bump, diffuse, specular maps?

(Note: I couldn't find it anywhere and I did quite a bit of searching)

Comment: Something like this is relatively easy to script, do you mean like a panel with slots for loading the filepaths of bump / diffuse / specular maps, and from that generate a generic starting point material which incorporates all of them?

Comment: That would do. I knew it would (probably) be easy to script, but I just thought it would cut 5 mins to 30 seconds at max. I just couldn't find it or script it myself.